# What does this Eclipse SVN icon mean?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

[image: Mysterious icon]
I sometimes see this icon in Eclipse when synchronizing repositories. It usually means that there will be some trouble as it doesn't want to disappear. I think it appears when Eclipse automatically builds a project while SVN is synchronizing. What does it mean? How does it differ from a blank blue arrow?

Edit: I asked on the Eclipse forum but nobody seems either to know or to bother writing an answer. I have no idea where in the huge source code of Eclipse and the various extensions resides the code that handles showing these icons. I would therefore be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction so I can investigate further.

Comment: stackoverflow is having problem with imgur.com or something, i can't see any images

Comment: http://imageshack.us/a/img546/5539/mysteryw.png

Comment: If I recall correctly, that'd mean there's incoming changes to the repo.

Comment: maybe! :) google image search can't find any similar image :)

Comment: @jornak: That would be the blue arrow without the inner white one, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some times since last post but I answer anyway.

the usual "white symbols" are :

- blank : item has been modified
- plus  : item is scheduled for addition
- minus : item is scheduled for deletion

The white arrow symbol means that the item has been replaced which means the file was scheduled for deletion and a new file with the same name was scheduled for addition in its place.

It corresponds to the SVN status letter R.

Hope this helps!

Nicolas

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its an incoming change from the repository.

I found this in another question:
Incoming

[image: First] A file that has content changes committed to the repository that will be applied to the local copy.

[image: Second] A new file that will be added to the local copy from the repository. Like the outgoing file addition, this may be the result of a move or rename.

[image: Third] A file that will be removed from the local copy because it has been removed from the repository. Like the outgoing file removal, this may be the result of a move or rename.

I think its the third one although I dont see the arrow.

Comment: It is not. I frequently see all three kinds you posted, that's usual business. The behavior is different though, it does not delete anything when I update. It also doesn't disappear when I update.

Answer (score 1):

[image: icon] means

> An incoming deletion icon means, that this resource 
>   was deleted from a repository location, but it's 
>   still contained in the local copy. It will be 
>   deleted from the local copy after update.

On the reference link below, there isn't exactly same icon i.e. with a folder+ arrow. Description for the overlay icons are given which signify the same icon above.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

[Reference link for eclipse svn icon set](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php)

Comment: Where on the reference page do you see this icon? I only see three - blank, with plus and with minus. There is no arrow with an arrow inside.

Comment: @JohnEye Update the answer. There is the icon, but with description is given with just the arrow image. Please see carefully. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't follow. It is a different icon and it has a _different_ function than the three mentioned in the reference. I know perfectly well how the other three work as I synchronize repositories daily.

Comment: @JohnEye Don't take the arrow image as different icon. They have just separated out the images for better description. What is confusing? Please let me now.

Comment: The situation is simple - blue arrow with nothing inside means a file has changed. Blue arrow with a plus sign inside means a file was added. Blue arrow with a minus sign inside means a file was deleted. Blue arrow with an arrow inside is different from the three others and its meaning is a mystery. Your answer confuses me because you seem to be suggesting (?) that the arrow with an arrow means the same thing as one of the three other icons, which is quite certainly not the case. Or do you know something I don't?